# How can I prevent duplicates in prolog

Tags: duplicates, prolog, transitive-closure

My multiple solution problem arises due to Prolog's backtracking looping through the goals. Whilst I understand that, technically, each solution provided is correct, it is not useful to me. Is there a method to remove duplicates?

Here is my code so far:

```
flight(london, paris).
flight(paris, amsterdam).
flight(amsterdam, rome).
flight(rome, paris).
flight(rome, rio_de_janeiro).
route_from(A,B) :-
  flight(A,B).
route_from(A,B) :-
  flight(A,R),
  route_from(R,B).
```

An example query is:

```
?- route_from(A, paris).
A = london ;
A = rome ;
A = london ;
A = london ;
A = london ;
A = london ;
A = london ;
A = london ;
A = london ;
etc.
```

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You have a bigger issue other than returning repeated solutions. Your program, as is, will loop indefinitely as there are loops in your graph.

To avoid loops you may maintain a list of visited cities:

```
route_from(A,B) :-
  route_from(A,B, []).

route_from(A,B, _) :-
  flight(A,B).
route_from(A,B, Visited) :-
  flight(A,R),
  \+ member(A, Visited),
  route_from(R,B, [A|Visited]).
```

Now, this won't prevent returning duplicates if there are more than one way to go to a city. You can use [`setof/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) to obtain every solution without duplicates upon backtracking:

```
route_from_without_duplicates(A,B):-
  setof(t, route_from(A,B), _).
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the purpose of \+?

Comment: Its negation (it succeeds if what is called fails); in this example it means that `A` should't be a member of `Visited`

Comment: `setof(t, route_from(A,B), _)` is more compact, less error prone and slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868):

```
?- closure(flight,A,B).
   A = london, B = paris
;  A = london, B = amsterdam
;  A = london, B = rome
;  A = london, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  A = paris, B = amsterdam
;  A = paris, B = rome
;  A = paris, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  A = amsterdam, B = rome
;  A = amsterdam, B = paris
;  A = amsterdam, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  A = rome, B = paris
;  A = rome, B = amsterdam
;  A = rome, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  false.
```

Apparently, there are no redundancies, but just in case:

```
?- setof(t,closure(flight,A,B),_).
   A = amsterdam, B = paris
;  A = amsterdam, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  A = amsterdam, B = rome
;  A = london, B = amsterdam
;  A = london, B = paris
;  A = london, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  A = london, B = rome
;  A = paris, B = amsterdam
;  A = paris, B = rio_de_janeiro
;  A = paris, B = rome
;  A = rome, B = amsterdam
;  A = rome, B = paris
;  A = rome, B = rio_de_janeiro.
```