# why does this not display the right answer

Tags: prolog

I have these facts and rules :

```
male(roelof).
male(mans). 
male(ronald).
male(jan).

female(chantal).
female(marie).
female(gerda).
female(dagmar).
female(denise).
female(kimberly).


parent(mans,gerda).
parent(mans,roelof).
parent(marie,gerda).
parent(marie,roelof).
parent(dagmar,denise).
parent(dagmar,kimberly).
parent(ronald,denise).
parent(ronald,kimberly).
parent(chantal,tamara).
parent(roelof,tamara).
parent(jan,chantal).
parent(jan,dagmar).

father_child(Father, Child) :-
 parent(Father, Child),
 male(Father).

mother_child(Mother, Child) :-
 parent(Mother, Child),
female(Mother).

child_father_mother(Child, Father, Mother) :-
 father_child(Father, Child),
 mother-child(Mother, Child).  

same_father(Child, Sibling) :-
 father_child(Father, Child),
 father_child(Father, Sibling).

same_mother(Child, Sibling) :-
  mother_child(Mother, Child),
  mother_child(Mother, Sibling).

siblings(Child, Sibling) :-
  same_father(Child, Sibling),
  Child \= Sibling.
siblings(Child, Sibling) :-
  same_mother(Child, Sibling),
  Child \= Sibling.

display_siblings(X,Y) :-
     setof(X-Y, (siblings(X,Y), \+X=Y), Sibs),
               member((X-Y,Y), Sibs),
               \+ (Y@<X, member((Y,X), Sibs)).
```

But when I do `display_siblings` I expected to see `roelof-gerda`.
But the output is only `x=roelof`

What did I do wrong.
Im a beginner at Prolog and try to understand how this works.

Roelof

Edit 1: Could this be a solution: [How can I prevent duplicates in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243081/how-can-i-prevent-duplicates-in-prolog)

Edit 2: I will do but I still do not understand why 'setof(X-Y, (siblings(X,Y), X @< Y), Sibs),write(Sibs).' is wrong. It works in both cases display_'siblings(gerda,X)' and 'display_siblings(X,Y)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your problem lies in your `display_siblings` predicate:

```
display_siblings(X,Y) :-
     setof(X-Y, (siblings(X,Y), \+X=Y), Sibs),
     member((X-Y,Y), Sibs),
     \+ (Y@<X, member((Y,X), Sibs)).
```

In the second line, the `\+X=Y` is superfluous since `siblings` already enforces that they are different. So that can be:

```
setof(X-Y, siblings(X,Y), Sibs),
```

The next line is querying whether `(X-Y,Y)` is a member of `Sibs`. However, `Sibs` consists of `X-Y` terms which will never match an `(X-Y,Y)` term. So this call to `member` will always fail. It should probably be:

```
member(X-Y, Sibs),
```

And then the last line is overly complex if all you want to do is eliminate symmetrical duplicates. You can simply use `X @< Y` and for efficiency, make this part of the `setof` check:

```
display_siblings(Sibs) :-
     setof(X-Y, (siblings(X,Y), X @< Y), Sibs).
```

This will yield:

```
?- display_siblings(Sibs).
Sibs = [chantal-dagmar, denise-kimberly, gerda-roelof].
```

If you want to select all of the siblings for a given person and still avoid the symmetry redundancies, you may need to process out those redundancies after the `setof`:

```
display_siblings(X, Sibs) :-
    setof(A-B, ((X = A ; X = B), siblings(A,B)), SibPairs),
    pack(SibPairs, Sibs).

pack([X-Y|T], Sibs) :-
    pack(T, SibList),
    (  member(Y-X, SibList)
    -> SibList = Sibs
    ;  Sibs = [X-Y|SibList]
    ).
pack([], []).

?- display_siblings(gerda, Sibs).
Sibs = [roelof-gerda].
```

Comment: Wierd, I changed it as you said and I see these solutions. display_siblings(gerda,X) true. and display_siblings(X,Y) gives true.The member part is no more a part of the rule?

Comment: @user3426797 if I understand the meaning of your predicate correctly, you don't need `member`.

Comment: oke, then somehow your rule does not work at my place. When I do this : http://pastebin.com/GtnpUkpn. I only see true or false.

Comment: @user3426797 if you put all your other data and predicates in (not including your version of `display_siblings`) and you enter `setof(X-Y, (siblings(X,Y), X @< Y), Sibs).` what do you get?

Comment: Then I see the outcome as you said. What is then the difference between enter in the prompt or making a rule of it.

Comment: found it. I have to add ,write(Sibs).

Comment: @user3426797 I had an error: instead of `write` you can have `Sibs` as an argument to `display_siblings`. I just forgot to add the argument. I updated the answer accordingly. Also, `X` and `Y` aren't necessary as arguments since they're part of the `setof`, not the solution or inputs.

Comment: When I changed that and so display_siblings(gerda). I see only false. When I do displays(X) I see the right answer.

Comment: @user3426797 That's because `display_siblings(Sibs)` assumes `Sibs` is a list of all sibling relationships. I think I misunderstood a little of what you wanted `display_siblings` to do. I will fix that...

Comment: I saw that you changed it.Can you explain to me what pack does. What is T and is it correct that -> is if then ? Personally I find the first one easier with using write(Sibs).

Comment: @user3426797 In this case, since we're trying to find a given `X`, I couldn't use `setof` to eliminate `X-Y` if `Y-X` existed. So they both might exist in the list. `pack` will remove `X-Y` if `Y-X` exists so you don't have both. If you just remove the `pack` query in the `display_siblings` predicate, you'll see what I mean when you run `display_siblings`.